# How is parsing being done in java (SimpleDateFormat)

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

First of all this is not a question how to parse a date, but what is the actual algorithm behind parsing. Imagine a situation when your code expects a certain input format, but gets input slightly different. Consider the example code:

Case 1 - as input we are expecting yyMM format, but someone inputs it as yyyyMM:

```
      String pattern = "yyMM";
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

      String inputDate = "201711";

        Date dateParsed = simpleDateFormat.parse(inputDate);
        System.out.println(dateParsed);

        String dateFormat = simpleDateFormat.format(dateParsed);
        System.out.println(dateFormat);
```

which gives the output: 6207 - deduction here is easy, as 201711 would be:

- yy=20 (year 2020)
- MM=12 + 5 (12 month + 5 as value transferred to
  next part of String)
- rest= 5 + 11 (511 months)

so we get a base date of 2020-12 and add 511 months to it resulting in 2062-07.

Case 2 - as input we are expecting yyMMdd format, but someone inputs it as yyyyMMdd:

```
      String pattern = "yyMMdd";
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

      String inputDate = "20171110";

        Date dateParsed = simpleDateFormat.parse(inputDate);
        System.out.println(dateParsed);

        String dateFormat = simpleDateFormat.format(dateParsed);
        System.out.println(dateFormat);
```

which gives output: 240514. Here I haven't deducted yet how it was done, but the general question is:

**What is the algorithm for parsing String and formatting it to a given date pattern ?**

Comment: Have you checked [open Java](http://openjdk.java.net/)?

Comment: ... or [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/DateFormat.java#DateFormat.parse%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Google for `Java SimpleDateFormat sourcecode` and you will find the sourcecode of the SimpleDateFormat and how it parses the Strings.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'm going through the sourcecode now

Comment: Any particular reason why you are asking about the long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class? Today I recommend that everyone uses [the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). The corresponding class is `DateTimeFormatter`, the important difference being that `SimpleDateFormat` notoriously behaves surprisingly. So if you insist on studying the old class, you may have quite a job to do.

Comment: @OleV.V. Hmm, I was just practicing with handling dates in java and SImpleDataFormat was a class that I found mentioned several times in some tutorials so took that one up... but thanks for the advice, I'll take a look at DateTimeFormatter then also

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` has been around for so long, so a lot has been written about it, and it’s very easy to stumble upon it. Or maybe so much needed to be written because the class is so troublesome? The modern API came out in 2014, so you should be able to find tutorials on it too.

Comment: Yeah, be careful when reading tutorials. Always check the year they were written in, as well as the reliability of the source. There are sites that look professional (like a certain rose*****.net), but the contents are mainly garbage.

Comment: When I run your code, I get `Thu Jul 01 00:00:00 CEST 2162`. The year is 2162, not 2062. I believe `201711` is taken to mean the 1711th month of 2020.

Comment: In case 2 you are getting the 1110th day of the 17th month of 2020, equivalent to 2024-05-14.